# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module when using retry-axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios-retry

```
const rax = require('retry-axios');

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module
```

I was trying to implement a retry mechanism with `retry-axios`. After installing the package I got the   `Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module` error. I’m not too sure what this ESM is, I’ve never dealt with it before, therefore I don’t know what to do to fix this.

Comment: ES modules use [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) instead of `require`.

Comment: @Geshode Thank you.

I have tried with import. But I got error.

import * as rax from 'retry-axios';
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Resolved by downgrading the retry-axios version to 2.6.0. https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry-axios/v/2.6.0

Answer (score 1):

There're 2 main syntax of JS

1. CJS - CommonJS (using const ... = require() )
2. ESM - ES Module (using import ... from "" )

Some library supports only one syntax, some supports both.
You can check library's main syntax from package.json
if there's field "type": "module" it means it supports only ESM syntax
You may need to use some alternative library